# How to disable apache logging when accessing certain directories?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, directory

How do I get apache to prevent http requests from being logged on a directory basis? I want to do something alike

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html

    <Directory /home/*/public_html/nolog>
        Options NoAccessLog
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set an environment flag whenever a specific URL is requested and filter logging based on that:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c> 
    UserDir public_html 

    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/nolog" dontlog
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/useraccess_log combined env=!dontlog
</IfModule>
```

All the related reading can be found at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html
Section "Using Environment Variables - Conditional Logging"

What these two lines do is, whenever a Client requests a URL that contains the string "/nolog" it sets the Environment Variable dontlog.

In the next line the option "env=!dontlog" tells the CustomLog directive to log Client access unless the variable dontlog is set. The ! negates the directive. If you would leave the ! so that it reads "env=dontlog" than it would *only* log access to paths that have "/nolog" in the requested URL.

EDIT: I removed the ^ in the "/nolog" regexp to work with your example and added some more explanation.

Comment: Doesn't work for me - access is still logged. Can you please elaborate your a bit more and integrate it in the given mod_userdir example? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to match your example. Basically you just leave out the ^ in the regexp. "^/nolog" would only match URLs like http://www.example.com/nolog/foobar but since you always have a Username first like http://www.example.com/~user/nolog/foobar it wouldn't match. So just remove the ^ and it should work.
Of course you can further tweak that regexp to include matching of the username, etc. Now it would match every URL that has the string "/nolog" in it.

Comment: I had trouble getting this to work ( apache 2.2.3 ) before switching from using graceful to using apachectl restart. Then it worked just fine.