# How to remove bloat from my logs automatically

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apache-2.4, logging, virtualhost

I was going over logs on a server with multiple vhosts/accounts, trying to figure which ones to delete because it is late in the month and an automated backup failed (I use Apache and/or Nginx).

I realized a good chunk of what is there is meaningless to me. I mean, I probably should log it because it it weren't working it would be symptomatic of a problem but entries log entries of cPanel initiated requests to `/.well-known/acme-challenge/...` or an "uptime monitoring" service that I use that checks every 5 minutes aren't useful to me in retrospect.

I'm assuming that setting up a `cron` task that runs `sed` at the end of the day or something would be able to handle this but I wouldn't want to edit the active log and all logs other than the active log are stored in gzipped archives `.gz`

I've never manually set up a `cron` job but it seems straight-forward enough but dealing with the compressed archive is something I'm not sure how to approach.

Sed is a "stream editor" is there a way for me to use it to filter the logs before they get compressed...maybe right when it is no longer the active log but before it's been archived?

Suggestions on how to do this, or existing software that does it?

I also find it pretty irritating that I have multiple logs for each...it looks like I have 3 access logs for each vhost, 1 standard log, an SSL log and a bytes(?) log, so even consolidating them will be an improvement.

I should note, I'm implementing `Fail2Ban` so that should a reduce the volume the logs somewhat but I don't want to turn the log level down too low.

A little help?

Comment: Instead of post-processing logs by removing irrelevant parts, it makes more sense to configure Apache/NGINX to not log requests in those specific locations. e.g. NGINX users would have `location /some/location/ { access_log off; }`

Comment: I usually use Apache behind an Nginx reverse proxy (Apache is more robust but Nginx is more efficient/performant at certain tasks so I find the combination works really well for me)...but I have always thought of Nginx Location directives as analogous to `mod_rewrite` rules/blocks...it hadn't occurred to me that I could just use it to control logging of that location. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Log file retention is the job of rotate and purge scripts, calling `logrotate`, `tmpwatch` or `find` commands. These are intended to automatically keep log file storage from filling up, absent some enormous increase in volume.  Usually not much processing here, to keep purge scripts simple. But you could remove some lines while compressing logs.

If URIs exist that should never be logged, the web server can be set to never log them.  [httpd example.](https://serverfault.com/q/119953/241174)

Sometimes a search engine helps make the number of log lines useful and manageable for humans. Consider forwarding logs to a text pipeline like Graylog or Logstash. Then extract signal from the noise. For example, a search for non-200 HTTP responses. Or, that 5 minute monitoring service could be turned into a secondary alert if the health check URI was *not* accessed in the past 10 minutes.

Comment: I voted this up as I haven't had time to look though everything mentioned yet and so I will try to remember to mark this answer as correct (when I have time to go through it in more detail) but there's nothing in it that makes me doubt it will be correct and useful. Thanks.